# Naïve pushforward of D-modules and Gauss–Manin connection

Tags: derived-categories, d-modules

Suppose that $f\colon X\to Y$ is a morphism of smooth quasi-projective varieties over a field of characteristic $0$. We then have a naïve pullback functor $f^\circ:=\mathcal D_{X\to Y}\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal D_Y}f^{-1}(-)$ from (left) $\mathcal D_Y$-modules to (left) $\mathcal D_X$-modules, where $\mathcal D_{X\to Y}$ is the transfer $(\mathcal D_X,f^{-1}\mathcal D_Y)$-bimodule. This functor $f^\circ$ is right-exact, and has a left-derived functor $\mathrm L f^\circ$.

Now the naive pullback $f^\circ$ has a right adjoint, namely the functor $f_\circ:=f_*\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal D_X}(\mathcal D_{X\to Y},-)$. Notably, this right adjoint is not in general the same as the “naïve pushforward” $f_*(\mathcal D_{Y\leftarrow X}\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal D_Y}(-))$, which is not even left-exact in general.

My question is this: **what is the right-derived functor $\mathrm Rf_\circ$ of $f_\circ$, and how is it related to other types of pushforward for $D$-modules?**

The reason I'm interested in this is that I already kinda know what the functor $\mathrm Rf_\circ$ is, but not in the language of $D$-modules. In the case that $f$ is smooth and proper, if we identify $\mathcal D_X$-modules with $\mathcal O_X$-modules with integrable connection, then $f_\circ$ is the functor $\mathcal E\mapsto f_*(\mathcal E^{\nabla_{X/Y}=0})$ (where $\nabla_{X/Y}$ is the relative connection on $\mathcal E$), i.e. $0$th relative de Rham cohomology with coefficients in $\mathcal E$. The higher derived functors of $f_\circ$ give higher relative de Rham cohomology [Katz70, Remark 3.1]. My interest comes in understanding how this picture fits into the setting of $D$-modules.

---

[Katz70] Nicholas M. Katz, *[Nilpotent connections and the monodromy theorem: applications of a result of Turrittin](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1970__39__175_0)*. Publ. math. de l'IHES, volume 39 (1970), pp. 175–232.